# sending carousel message but smooch rendering it as text, description link only

Tags: json, smooch

I am sending carousel message to smooch, carousel is rendering as text in smooch but in facebook messenger carousel get rendered. Needs carousel in smooch web messanger.

Here is json

```
msg = {
"role": 'appMaker',
"type": 'carousel',
"items": [{
    "title": 'Tacos',
    "description": 'Description',
    "mediaUrl": 'https://example.com/img.png',
    "actions": [{
        "text": 'Select',
        "type": 'postback',
        "payload": 'TACOS'
    }, {
        "text": 'More info',
        "type": 'link',
        "uri": 'https://example.com'
    }]
}, {
    "title": 'Ramen',
    "description": 'Description',
    "mediaUrl": 'https://example.com/img.png',
    "actions": [{
        "text": 'Select',
        "type": 'postback',
        "payload": 'RAMEN'
    }, {
        "text": 'More info',
        "type": 'link',
        "uri": 'https://example.com'
    }]
}]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the time of writing, Carousel messages are currently not supported on the Smooch SDKs (Web Messenger, iOS, and Android). See the section [Channel Support](https://docs.smooch.io/rest/#channel-support) in the documentation for the Post Carousel Message API for details on how a carousel will render on each channel.

You can also get at-a-glance information about feature support across channels using the Smooch [channel capabilities grid](https://docs.smooch.io/guide/channel-capabilities/). For those marked as "partial channel support", it means the carousel will render a text fallback, as you're describing.

Comment: Still no support for Carousel in the Web SDK ?